# How should I run a Server/Client Code?

Tags: java, networking, client

i just started writing my first Server/Client code and its a simple chat program , but i dont know how should I run the Code !

there is a .class file named Server Side , and a .class file named clientSide , are they supposed to be in different projects ? how should I run it so they both have a connection together ? thanks already ,following is a part of the codes

```
public void runServer()
    {
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket();
            while(true)
            {
                try
                {
                    connection = server.accept();
                    try{
                        output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream()) ;
                        output.flush(); 
                        input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream()) ;
                        sendData(message) ;
                        do
                        {
                            try{
                                message = (String) input.readObject() ;
                                System.out.println(message);
                            }catch(Exception e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace() ;
                            }
                        }while(!message.equals("end"));
                    }catch(EOFException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace() ;
                    }   
                }catch(IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace() ;
                }           
                finally {
                    try{
                    output.close();
                    input.close();
                    connection.close() ;
                    }catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    }
            }
        }catch(Exception e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    }
```

and here's the clientSide :

```
public void runClient()
    {
            try{
            connect() ;
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                output = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream()) ;
                output.flush() ;
                input = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream()) ;
            }catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace() ;
            }
            do
            {
                try{
                    message = (String) input.readObject() ;
                    System.out.println(message);
                }catch(Exception e)
                {e.printStackTrace();}
            }while(!message.equals("end")) ;

    }
    public void connect() throws UnknownHostException, IOException
    {
        client = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(chatServer),12345) ;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First run the server

> java Server

Then run the client:

> java Client

But I do not see your server bound to the port 12345. The client will try to connect to the server on the port 12345 because of the statement

```
client = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(chatServer),12345) ;
```

If the ports do not match, the connection will not be established.

To bind the server to the port 12345 try this:

```
server = new ServerSocket(12345);
```

instead of the default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very nice tutorial where you have all described:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

You should do 2 files one for server one for client,in two distinct packages :client and server.